# How can I make timeshift take a backup of the whole system?

Tags: backup, timeshift

How can I make timeshift take a backup of the whole system? I am unable to find any tutorials to do this! I am using the default config.

Comment: See if the answer is good enough. I took the liberty to add the suggested tool from the timeshift github Clonezilla will work too. but ... please don't try to get or give more info through comments. Edit the question if you need to clarify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't as it is not designed to do that.

> [Timeshift](https://github.com/teejee2008/timeshift) is similar to applications like rsnapshot, BackInTime and TimeVault but with different goals. **It is designed to protect only system files and settings**. User files such as documents, pictures and music are excluded. This ensures that your files remains unchanged when you restore your system to an earlier date. If you need a tool to backup your documents and files please take a look at the excellent [BackInTime](https://github.com/bit-team/backintime) application which is more configurable and provides options for saving user files.

- BackInTime is suggested

From the link:

> Back In Time is a simple backup tool for Linux, inspired by "flyback project".
>
> It provides a command line client 'backintime' and a Qt5 GUI 'backintime-qt' both written in Python3.
>
> You only need to specify 3 things:
>
> - where to save snapshots
> - what folders to backup
> - backup frequency (manual, every hour, every day, every month)

- The second thing noted seems to indicate a full backup can be created by telling it to backup `/`.
- Generic tools like Clonezilla or a manually custom made command will work too.

===

A full system backup should be done from unmounted partitions and the live session is the easiest tool to do that from. That is also the reason most people do not make full system backups and only backup personal files: if the system itself is busted and there is no way to fix it, restoring a backup is probably easiest from a live session too. But a re-install is going to be even easier: I myself use an SSD for my system and a HDD for my personal files. A re-install is done within 20 minutes (and that includes post-install extra installation of software I use that is not default).

Comment: I added an extra comment on that :)

Answer (score 1):

While Rinzwind's answer is good in the cases where you want to follow best practices - the sad reality is that a janky backup is better than grandstanding and saying to download an entirely new application instead. So I'll offer my two cents here:

Getting Timeshift to backup everything can be a little tricky. Most importantly, the GUI is pretty bad for explaining priority via the list ordering as well as the add/remove action.

For me I like to edit the JSON manually but if you do this you can break timeshift so make a backup. **Before you do this though, make sure you go through the full timeshift setup wizard to set the defaults in the JSON file like `backup_device_uuid`**

1. `sudo su` switch to the root user
2. `cd /` switch to the root directory
3. `find . -type f -name "timeshift.json"` find your timeshift
   json file (mine is at /etc/timeshift/timeshift.json)
4. `ls -la /etc/timeshift/timeshift.json` check your permissions - mine is owned by root
5. `sudo cp /etc/timeshift/timeshift.json /etc/timeshift/timeshift.json.bak` **make a local copy before editing**
6. `sudo subl /etc/timeshift/timeshift.json` use sudo to open the json file in sudo mode. if you don't have sublime text installed you can use gedit

You can enable your home folders manually within Timeshift but adding lots of directories can be tiresome so that's where the manual editing comes in. I'll paste mine below. If you ever get a hard crash from Timeshift it's probably for invalid JSON. You can start it via terminal `CTRL+ALT+T -> timeshift &` to see the log output. Alternatively, you can use [DuckDuckGO's JSON validator](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=json%20validator&ia=answer) to make sure yours is valid.

What I like to do is modify the JSON, run timeshift, view the logs to see what was created, close timeshift `sudo rm -rfv /timeshift` or similar to delete all the snapshots (YMMV on the folder location), and do that over and over until it gets it right.

Why would I recommend people modify the JSON file? Because the binary is infuriating. It provides no clear documentation on what order to put things in and moreover it rearranges items or even deletes them from the `exclude` property list without telling you.

Here's my `exclude` json property for others to copy from. I'm a developer obviously so I want to keep a lot of JS,Py, and GO state out of my backups.

Also remember **exclusions have to come before inclusions**.

```
  "exclude" : [
    "- /home/userhome/.aws/**",
    "- /home/userhome/.cache/**",
    "- /home/userhome/.docker/**",
    "- /home/userhome/.java/**",
    "- /home/userhome/.local/**",
    "- /home/userhome/.mozilla/**",
    "- /home/userhome/.npm/**",
    "- /home/userhome/.nvm/**",
    "- /home/userhome/.serverless/**",
    "- /home/userhome/.terraform.d/**",
    "- **site-packages/**",
    "- **venv/**",
    "- **pkg/mod/**",
    "- **pkg/sumdb/**",
    "- **node_modules/**",
    "+ /home/userhome/**",
    "+ /root/**"
  ],
```

Hope this helps someone out there. Backups are always a good thing and Timeshift is very finicky.