# TimeShift: Revert the system after installing a new OS

Tags: system-installation, backup, timeshift

I am planning to switch my *only* computer to Fedora. In case, the new system doesn't work for me or exhibits serious issues, I would like to revert the system back to my currently installed one, including the current configuration and installed applications. From time to time, I made system backups using TimeShift and I don't care about user data (backed up separately). Is it possible to restore an *overwritten* system from these backups using a live system or will I have to install Ubuntu 22.04 first to revert the system to its current state?

I have already found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1304122/how-can-i-make-timeshift-take-a-backup-of-the-whole-system), but it doesn't quite answer my question (explicitly).

Comment: not Timeshift but I have used Clonezilla for years and many many times have I used it. you make a boot USB. It backs up the whole drive, or partition. Generally I do a backup before any updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, that should be possible to do with Timeshift.

Anyway, your personal data are safe in a backup. So there is no risk trying it. If it does not work, you still have your plan B, installing Ubuntu first before restoring. And if that fails, there is still plan C: a fresh install and manual reconfiguration. As long as your user data are safe, not a lot can fundamentally go wrong.

Comment: Yes, I better prepare an USB stick with both, Fedora and Ubuntu, to be sure. That way, I should be able to manually restore the system.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed Timeshift and noticed that the setup wizard explicitly states that Timeshift does allow restoring snapshots on top of re-installed systems. This is a useful piece of information that re-assures deleting the old system is safe -- as long as I have a method to install the base system (e.g., Ubuntu 22.04), I can restore my snapshots.

[image: Setup wizard of Timeshift stating useful information about how to use Timeshift (in German), notably mentioning that shapshots can be used on top of a re-installed system.]